# How to get the index value in pandas MultiIndex data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,3,5], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c':[12,13,14]})
df.set_index(['a','b'], inplace=True)
display(df)
s = df.iloc[1]
# How to get 'a' and 'b' value from s?
```

It is so annoying that ones columns become indices we cannot simply use df['colname'] to fetch values.

Does it encourage we use `set_index(drop=False)`?

Answer (score 20):

When I print s I get

```
In [8]: s = df.iloc[1]

In [9]: s
Out[9]:  
c    13
Name: (3, 2), dtype: int64
```

which has a and b in the name part, which you can access with:

```
s.name
```

Something else that you can do is

```
df.index.values
```

and specifically for your iloc[1]

```
df.index.values[1]
```

Does this help? Other than this I am not sure what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get "a" and "b"

df.index.names

gives:
FrozenList(['a', 'b'])